# Выбор всех checkbox в div

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Здравствуйте.
Не получается сделать все checkbox активными в конкретном div по нажатию на кнопку.

Вот html:

```
<button class="button" id="checkAll"">Выбрать все</button>
<div id="sites">
    <input type="checkbox" name="p1" value="1" >1</br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="p2" value="2" >2 </div>
</div>
```

Ни просто на js, не на jQuery не получается.

Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button class="button" id="checkAll">Выбрать все</button>
<div id="sites">
    <input type="checkbox" name="p1" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="p2" value="2">
</div>

<script>
    $('#checkAll').click(function(){
        $('#sites input').prop('checked', true);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ваш вариант только устанавливает флаги, но не снимает их при следующем нажатии

Comment: ну так и задачи такой и не стояло :)

Comment: @spart, обычно одна одна и та же кнопка должна и выделять все и снимать все

Comment: Действительно. Мне нужно было выделение только. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Например [вот](http://jsfiddle.net/u4gwf/2/)

Comment: при снятии 1 галки посмотрите как себя ведет код

Comment: и в чем проблема?

Comment: Выделяем все галочки (1-2).
Убираем руками выделение с галочки 1.(галочка 2 выделена)
Нажимаем кнопку выделить все.
Выделение с галочки 2 убирается, но у галочки 1 оно появляется.

Браузер Mozilla Firefox 28.0

Comment: действительно, косяк. Поправил

Comment: Теперь все отлично! Спасибо!
Просто случайно увидел решил вам сообщить.

Comment: ещё минорный косяк :) если нажать чтобы все убрались, а потом руками поставить все галки то кнопка никак не сработает :)

Answer (score 0):

вот на чистом js http://jsfiddle.net/GcXXW/

Comment: тоже самое поведение, что и у DreamChild

Comment: как-то так можно сделать http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/GcXXW/2/

Comment: @NMD, так код был написан за минуту)) чего вы хотели?))

Comment: @mountpoint я думаю @NMD хотел, чтобы коды был как минимум лучше предложенного @spart, например выполнял бы запрошенные ОП функции  и заявленные вами в комментарии.
а так получается - "я это вот на ассемблере могу! посмотрите как круто!" многие могут, но кнопки инвертирования значений списка чекбоксов точно никто не запрашивал.